# why I get an 401 error when i upload a file to video indexer

Tags: azure, api, access-token, http-status-code-401, azure-video-indexer

I've created a logic app that uploads a video file from OneDrive to VideoIndexer for processing.
Im getting an 401 error.

```
{
  "ErrorType": "USER_NOT_ALLOWED",
  "Message": "Access token does not have 'Contributor' permission. Trace id: '*****'."
}
```

** Im using a Trial account
** the error happened in callback url step

I tried to give a contributor access in the IAM account of my Media service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Trial account you need to retrieve a token using the dataplane API
https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Get-Account-Access-Token

Make sure you select "trial" as region and that you create a token with "edit" permission scope.

- FvN

Comment: thanks, i changed it to permission "edit". 
It helped.

Comment: If I do this I get another error, do you have any idea what could it be? {
  "ErrorType": "INVALID_INPUT",
  "Message": "Url content type 'text/html' is not supported. Only audio and video files are supported. You can find the supported types here: https://aka.ms/upload-standard-formats. Trace id: 'b96696d8-381b-4a2e-91f3-da1883680e8f'."
}

Comment: Looks like you're trying to point or upload a file that is not a media file (or at least the mime-type is telling it's text/html). You need to upload a media file like mp4/mov/wav/mp3 etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/faq#what-media-formats-does-azure-video-indexer-support